# Changing controls properties from other class

Tags: c#, compact-framework, label

I'm using CompactFramework to make a WinCE App.

I have a Form1 and a Class1. In the Form1 I have a label1 which I need to get access from Class1.

If I try:

```
Form1.label1
```

it doesn't appear, despite I set Modifier property to public.

How could I get access to the label?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post the code of the label1 property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Form1 is a class, and you need an instance of that class, because your label is not static.

var myForm = new Form1();
myForm.label1.Text = "hello";

Obviously you don't want to create the new form from your class, because your application likely created the form.

So you should pass the form into the class. Does the class get instantiated by the form? If so you can pass "this" into the class to send a reference to the instantiated form.

But really, you don't want to do this, because its difficult to maintain. Better would be to have the class raise some sort of event that the form could subscribe to to update itself.

Comment: You were right, I make an event to update my label. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can instance Form1 to Class1 and then use this instance to set Form1.label1.
This would be an elegant solution. Check this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Label Label1 { get; set; }

    public void Caller()
    {
        MyClass cls = new MyClass();
        cls.Form1 = this;
        cls.DoSomeJob();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public Form1 Form1 { get; set; }

    public void DoSomeJob()
    {
        Form1.Label1.Text = "Some text...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create property or method on the Form1 class to return label1 object